# Upload CSV files into partitioned bigquery table (generate partition from file name)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am using bigquery client object to upload some CSV files (located in cloud storage) into a bigquery table.

I managed to upload the data into a bigquery table but I want to change the destination table to a partitioned table. And partition will be date which is in the filename.

***filename** is a column in the CSV file which is the same as CSV file name.*

This is how I extract date from filename (assume text is filename) date1 will be used as our partition later:

```
text = 'sales_2022-09-09T21-27-05_018787'
match = re.search(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', text)
date1 = datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

and this is how to upload data into BQ:

```
client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(CREDENTIALS_LOCATION)
def upload_from_gcs_to_bq(project_id, dataset_id, gsutil_uri, table_name,gcs_blob):
    table_id = project_id +'.'+ dataset_id +'.'+ table_name

    uri = gsutil_uri + '/' + gcs_blob +'.csv'

    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        schema=[
            bigquery.SchemaField("filename", "STRING"),
            bigquery.SchemaField("sales_category", "STRING"),
            ...
        ],

        skip_leading_rows=1,
        # time_partitioning=bigquery.TimePartitioning(
        #     type_=bigquery.TimePartitioningType.DAY,
        #     field="date",  # Name of the column to use for partitioning.
        #     expiration_ms=7776000000,  # 90 days.
        # ),
    )    
    load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
        uri, table_id, job_config=job_config
    ) 
    load_job.result()  # Wait for the job to complete.
    table = client.get_table(table_id)

def main():
    upload_from_gcs_to_bq(project_id, dataset_id, gsutil_uri, table_name,gcs_blob)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You have to first ingest your CSV and then query the data, select the correct date in the data, and sink the result in the target table. Or, you have to stream the file contend directly from your Python code (and you won't use the Load Job feature and therefore you will pay for the ingestion)

Comment: Hi @Sana, is your issue resolved?

Comment: Hi @ShipraSarkar no I am still struggling

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to take advantage of external tables, given that your data is already being stored in cloud storage.

You can create external table, permanent or temporary, by reading directly the CSV files.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-cloud-storage

And then load the information to a table partitioned by the field you are aiming for.

If you have partitioned files, there is also a nice option to load them as external tables but you need to follow a specific format in cloud storage

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/hive-partitioned-queries-gcs